# How to make jar from a spagoBi source edited java file?

Tags: java, jar, spagobi

I have edited `LDAPConnector.java` file from the spagobi source code. How can I build jar for the same and replace it with origin?

Comment: Unpack the jar, replace the class, repack the jar ?

Comment: so how could I make class file for the same? as it has lots of dependencies and many libraries linked to it.

Comment: I have extracted class files from jar file and edited with my class file, now how can I convert it back to jar?

Comment: You may just create a zip file and put all the classes , directories and the manifest file in it like in the original jar. Then, rename your archive with a `.jar` extension .

Comment: Some grammar improvements - I think your question isn't "spagobi"-specific, you only want to replace a class in a jar. But: if you ask a question, end it with a "?"!